# In Python async is it possible to provide an async generator with the context of if's caller?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a 'chain' of async tasks, i.e. task which `gather`/`await` other tasks with an arbitrary depth.
Now I want an 'upper' task (i.e. one that `await`s 'lower' tasks, which might then `await` yet lower tasks) to provide one of the 'lower' tasks with some contextual information, e.g. some logging object which might not yet exist when the lower task gets created.

```py
async def compute(args):
    #
    # Here we don't know (yet) when or by whom this function get's awaited
    #
    logger = global_loggers[find_context(asyncio.current_task())]
    .. do stuff ..
    logger.write("something that goes somewhere")
    yield stuff
    logger.write("something that goes somewhere")
    yield stuff
    logger.write("something that goes somewhere")
    ..


async def some_weired_scheduler():
    #
    # this function doesn't make sense, it's just here to make the `await` queue deeper
    ..
    tasks_for_later.append(asyncio.gather(compute(<args1>), compute(<args2>)))
    ..

async def logging_executor():
    #
    # here we invoke the compute-generators and we want to 'inject' some runtime
    # environment, in this case it's just a logger
    #
    logger = MyLogger()
    global_loggers[find_context(asyncio.current_task())] = logger

    for t in tasks_for_later:
        await t
```

Is there some built in way to accomplish something like this? Is there something like a 'task stack' where I can see what task `await`s what another `yield`s or `return`s?
Doesn't `Quart` do something like this with it's global `request` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there something like a 'task stack' where I can see what task awaits what another yields or returns?"

Yes. It is called "contextvars" - https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html

It does exactly what you need - including, in a case where you need just one value to be known in a "subtask in the same call stack", you could create "loggers" as a `contextvars.ContextVar`  in itself.

Note that several of the calls in asyncio allow you to pass a context - which will hold its own copy of all existing contextvars - explicitly. It is a bit awkward to use in that one can only "switch" a context by making a function call - either a call that will acept a context as parameter explicitly, or by using the `context.run` method.

(Unfortunately, your example code is not a stand-alone script, and I failed to understand how you would orchestrate the calls to `some_weird_scheduler` and `logging_executor` - so that I could make it a working script with contextvars)